# Sticky Bit and SELinux

Tags: linux, selinux

I recently got the question how sticky bit and SELinux play together. I only found this one site about [Linux Permissions on Fedora](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting-Fixing_Problems.html#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Linux_Permissions)

Are there any other concerns using sticky bits and SELinux together?

Comment: I edited your question, feel free to revert or edit it again if you are unhappy with the changes.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you are concerned that Sticky Bit might behave strange on SELinux?

Comment: Thanks for editing. No, someone asked me that question, and it got me curious. I only found the link posted and I thought I'd put that question out to a broader audience, since it's not an everyday question.

Answer (score 2):

SELinux just prohibits some operations that the "standard Unix" permission model would allow. The sticky bit on a directory means that only the owner of a file in it can fiddle with it. On files the sticky bit hasn't meant anything for almost as long as memory serves.